# jQuery worked yesterday. Not anymore

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, debugging

Yeah, so I have NO CLUE what happened. I've been writing an AJAX comment script and I got it working, except it doesn't work anymore. I restored it from a backup just in case I chaged anything, but no luck. It goes to the "action" of the form instead of the jQuery, even though I have `return false;` This leads me to believe that one of the following things is wrong: I'm not including the jQuery correctly (which I am) or I have a syntax error. Do you see anything?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#alert").hide();

    $('form').submit(function() {

        $("#alert").slideUp().delay(1000);
        name = $('input[name=name]').val();
        email = $('input[name=email]').val();
        timestamp = $('input[name=timestamp]').val();
        entry_title = $('input[name=entry_title]').val();
        message = $('textarea[name=message]').val();
        $.post("/scripts/ajax_comment.php", {comm_name:name, comm_email:email, comm_message:message, comm_timestamp:timestamp, comm_entry_title:entry_title}, function(data){

            switch(data) {
                case "invalid email" : $("#alert").val("").append("Invalid E-mail address.").slideDown();
                break;

                case "empty field" : $("#alert").val("").append("Make sure no fields are empty.").slideDown();
                break;

                case "error" : alert("error");
                break;

                default: $(data).appendTo("#messages").hide().slideDown().animate({ color: "#669900" }, 1000).animate({ color: "#000000" }, 1000); 
            }   
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

SOLVED: The problem was the delay(1000);

Comment: are there any errors on the firefox error console?

Comment: Make sure you post your answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're doing here:

```
$("#alert").slideUp().delay(1000);
```

jQuery 1.4's [`$.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) is suppose to precede an action, if I'm not mistaken.
You might want to remove that or complete that line - whichever is correct for your project. I see no other problems that would prevent this from succeeding.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Javascript enabled on your browser? Do you see any error messages in the console? If you put an alert in the document ready handler is it triggered?

Answer (score 0):

I don't now if this leads to an error, but shouldn't be the keys of the JSON string enwrapped in quotation marks (I guess they are strings)? Like:

```
{'comm_name':name, 
 'comm_email':email, 
 'comm_message':message, 
 'comm_timestamp':timestamp, 
 'comm_entry_title':entry_title}
```

If you use Firefox, install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and check the console for error messages.... Firebug helps a lot when developing websites.

Comment: or in Chrome, press Ctrl-Shift-J to open the JavaScript debugger